# Sharing generic code between UWP projects

Tags: c#, uwp, winmd

I'm developing an UWP app via C#, that uses [IBasicVideoEffect with IDirect3DSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects). As mentioned in documentation, I have created Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows) project.

But settings of effects are stored in some implementation of [IPropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Collections.IPropertySet?view=winrt-22000) (smth like [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)<object, object>).

To use high - level operations on this storage, I've introduced `IPropertySetExtensions` into runtime component, that has for example `Get<T>`, `GetOrDefault<T>` methods, which return instance of `T` (not `object`) from storage.

Than I realized, that same operations will be needed in main project, but when I changed

`internal static class IPropertySetExtensions`  into `public` one, I got an error like "winmd components cant contain generic methods".
That's why I duplicated extension class into main project.

How can I avoid this duplicating? Maybe move shared code into NuGet .dll or smth?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/diagnosing-windows-runtime-component-error-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when writing a WinRT Component there are quite a few limitations due to the fact that WinRT Components are usable in C++, C#, VB and JS (yes also JS). The following document covers part of what to watch out for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic

In your case, I think creating a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" will solve that problem since you can write C# code as you like without having to watch out for WinRT Component limitations.